# How to display a div tag in bloggers blogspot pages?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I have created a page named *Bank* and want to customize it using HTML.
But when using `<div>` tag it is not rendering. Here is my code....

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <p style="background-color: burlywood; font-size:24">here are my three div tags</p>
    <div style="background-color: silver;margin-left: 10;visibility:visible; height:300; width:200; margin-left:10;display:inline-block"></div>
    <div style="background-color: silver; height:300; width:200;visibility:visible; display:inline-block ; margin-block-end: 10"></div>
    <div style="background-color: silver; height:300; width:200; display:inline-block" ></div>
    <p style="background-color:burlywood; font-size: 24">here my div tag ended but not rendering</p>
</div>
```

Here is my output

[image: xxxenter image description herexxx]
I have also switched from show HTML literally to interpret HTML. In page settings=> options => interpret typed HTML.

Comment: give text to `div` tag. fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/4Lbg7okh/**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a length unit like `px` with height, width, margin and font-size

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
        <p style="background-color: burlywood; font-size:24px">here are my three div tags</p>
     <div style="background-color: silver;margin-left: 10px;visibility:visible; height:300px; width:200px; margin-left:10px;display:inline-block"></div>
     <div style="background-color: silver; height:300px; width:200px;visibility:visible; display:inline-block ; margin-block-end: 10px"></div>
     <div style="background-color: silver; height:300px; width:200px; display:inline-block" ></div>
     <p style="background-color:burlywood; font-size: 24px">here my div tag ended but not rendering</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify your measurement unit.

The font-size CSS property, for example, specifies the size of the font. Setting this property may change the size of other items, too, since it is used to compute the value of em, ex, and various other relative  units.

The same apply for your margins.

I hope this helps. For more info, check out the standards for assigning values to css properties.